# Revoke drive access through Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-drive-android-api

Is there a way to revoke drive access granted through Google Play Services?

Referring to this article:
https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html

I granted access to g drive from my app like so:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.addApi(Drive.API)
.addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
.addConnectionCallbacks(this)
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
.build();
```

My question is, is there a clean way to revoke g drive access

i.e. without needing to do credential.getToken() and making http call to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=

I'm looking for something like Drive.DriveApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect();

I know there is one for g plus, but i cant find one for g drive. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/Account.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an method for revoking of Google Drive scope.

```
GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = buildGoogleSignInClient();
googleSignInClient.revokeAccess().addOnCompleteListener(onCompleteListener);
```

where

```
private GoogleSignInClient buildGoogleSignInClient() {
    GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =
            new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .build();
    return GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);
}
```

For more information, you can check this [reference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInClient#revokeAccess())